# How to align an item in navbar to the center in HTML

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core

I would like to move this **h5** element such that it always hangs in the middle of the navbar. How can I control that. This is the HTML from a shared layout file that will be shared across all pages. Thank you

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">ProjectX1</a>

    <h5 class="display-6 navbar-text">@ViewData["NavbarTitle"]</h5>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
      <partial name="_LoginPartial.cshtml" />
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to remove `navbar-collapse` of `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">...</div>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center "  > 
        <h5 class="display-6 navbar-text text-center">@ViewData["NavbarTitle"]</h5>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox:

```
nav > .container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```